# Cannot displaying Blob image in JSP in HTTPS

Tags: image, jsp, https, blob

I am trying to retrieve a blob from database and display it in jsp
Here is the code :

```
response.setContentType("image/bmp");
con = dbMon.connect(Con_id);
stmt = con.createStatement(); 
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);   
while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
  out.clear(); 
  OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream(); 
  os.write(rs.getBytes("IMAGE"));  
  out.flush(); 
  dbMon.close(con);
}
```

The code work fine in our uat environment which is using http, but fail in production environment which is HTTPS
In production, when the image going to display, a Security Warning will prompt will message 
"Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely ?
 This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage."

1. If I choose Yes , the image will not be shown.
2. If I choose No, only a bad image logo ( a red cross) will be shown
   Anyone have idea ? Please kindly help 
   Thanks

Comment: What your image url? start with "http" or "https" ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not using url to access the image, but call another jsp to write the blob image out. like this :  < img src="showImage.jsp" width="100" height="100" border="0">

Comment: Try to using full path as src like  "https ://yourdomain.com/showImage.jsp"

Comment: I have tried to hardcode the full path as mentioned, the image doesn't show (no warning any more but a bad image red cross ). I wonder is it a issue of encrypt / decrypt problem on blob for HTTPS ? (Our uat & production envirnment are connect to same DB and getting the same blob)